# R + Arrow 10 : convert blank to numeric NA

Tags: r, na, apache-arrow

Please have a look at the reprex at the end of the post.
I need to read a column as a string, perform several manipulations and then save convert it to a numerical column.
The blanks ("") in the string column give me a headache because arrow does not convert them to numerical missing values NA.

Does anybody know how to achieve that?
Many thanks

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(arrow)
#> Some features are not enabled in this build of Arrow. Run `arrow_info()` for more information.
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'arrow'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     timestamp


df <- tibble(x=rep(c("4000 -", "6000 -",  "", "8000 - "), 10),
             y=seq(1,10, length=40))

write_csv(df, "test_string.csv")


data <- open_dataset("test_string.csv",
                     format="csv",
                     skip=1,
                     schema=schema(x=string(), y=double()))


data2 <- data |>
    mutate(x= sub(" -.*", "", x)   ) |>
    mutate(x2=as.numeric(x)) |>
    collect() ## how to convert the blank to a numeric NA ?
#> Error in `collect()`:
#> ! Invalid: Failed to parse string: '' as a scalar of type double

#> Backtrace:
#>     ▆
#>  1. ├─dplyr::collect(mutate(mutate(data, x = sub(" -.*", "", x)), x2 = as.numeric(x)))
#>  2. └─arrow:::collect.arrow_dplyr_query(mutate(mutate(data, x = sub(" -.*", "", x)), x2 = as.numeric(x)))
#>  3.   └─base::tryCatch(...)
#>  4.     └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
#>  5.       └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
#>  6.         └─value[[3L]](cond)
#>  7.           └─arrow:::augment_io_error_msg(e, call, schema = x$.data$schema)
#>  8.             └─rlang::abort(msg, call = call)
 


sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
#> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#> Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
#> LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.13.so
#> 
#> locale:
#>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
#>  [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
#>  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
#>  [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
#>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
#> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] arrow_10.0.0    forcats_0.5.2   stringr_1.4.1   dplyr_1.0.10   
#>  [5] purrr_0.3.5     readr_2.1.3     tidyr_1.2.1     tibble_3.1.8   
#>  [9] ggplot2_3.4.0   tidyverse_1.3.2
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] lubridate_1.9.0     assertthat_0.2.1    digest_0.6.30      
#>  [4] utf8_1.2.2          R6_2.5.1            cellranger_1.1.0   
#>  [7] backports_1.4.1     reprex_2.0.2        evaluate_0.17      
#> [10] httr_1.4.4          highr_0.9           pillar_1.8.1       
#> [13] rlang_1.0.6         googlesheets4_1.0.1 readxl_1.4.1       
#> [16] R.utils_2.12.1      R.oo_1.25.0         rmarkdown_2.17     
#> [19] styler_1.8.0        googledrive_2.0.0   bit_4.0.4          
#> [22] munsell_0.5.0       broom_1.0.1         compiler_4.2.2     
#> [25] modelr_0.1.9        xfun_0.34           pkgconfig_2.0.3    
#> [28] htmltools_0.5.3     tidyselect_1.2.0    fansi_1.0.3        
#> [31] crayon_1.5.2        tzdb_0.3.0          dbplyr_2.2.1       
#> [34] withr_2.5.0         R.methodsS3_1.8.2   grid_4.2.2         
#> [37] jsonlite_1.8.3      gtable_0.3.1        lifecycle_1.0.3    
#> [40] DBI_1.1.3           magrittr_2.0.3      scales_1.2.1       
#> [43] vroom_1.6.0         cli_3.4.1           stringi_1.7.8      
#> [46] fs_1.5.2            xml2_1.3.3          ellipsis_0.3.2     
#> [49] generics_0.1.3      vctrs_0.5.0         tools_4.2.2        
#> [52] bit64_4.0.5         R.cache_0.16.0      glue_1.6.2         
#> [55] hms_1.1.2           parallel_4.2.2      fastmap_1.1.0      
#> [58] yaml_2.3.6          timechange_0.1.1    colorspace_2.0-3   
#> [61] gargle_1.2.1        rvest_1.0.3         knitr_1.40         
#> [64] haven_2.5.1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifelse` works here when all classes are correct (and not `double()`); `if_else` enforces this already, so we can use either.

```r
data |>
  mutate(x = sub(" -.*", "", x)) |>
  mutate(
    x = ifelse(x == "", NA_character_, x),  # also if_else works
    x2 = as.numeric(x)
  ) |>
  collect()
# # A tibble: 40 x 3
#    x         y    x2
#    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 4000   1     4000
#  2 6000   1.23  6000
#  3 NA     1.46    NA
#  4 8000   1.69  8000
#  5 4000   1.92  4000
#  6 6000   2.15  6000
#  7 NA     2.38    NA
#  8 8000   2.62  8000
#  9 4000   2.85  4000
# 10 6000   3.08  6000
# # ... with 30 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the best workaround available, but the behavior of arrow is counterintuitive here. @Ruam Pimentel: in real life I deal with a large dataset and I do not want to load everything into memory.

Comment: @larry77, I don't disagree that there are gaps, but I would personally label them as "incomplete", not necessarily "counterintuitive". The list of supported "R" functions that are translated to arrow-aware processing is loosely defined at places in its NEWS/changelog, I think it would be very useful for them to have a single list of such functions (or perhaps they do and I haven't found it yet).

Comment: I think the list is here https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/acero.html . I should agree with you: certain things are work in progress and incomplete by necessity. In any case, far from me any destructive criticism: arrow is a wonderful project!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `read_csv` instead of `open_dataset`

```
library(readr)
data <- read_csv("test_string.csv")
```

Comment: larry77's intent is to open these files within the `arrow::open_dataset` mechanism. While it's unstated in the question, many of their previous questions have done better at communicating that (I know this from following their questions). While your answer is technically correct for just getting at the data, larry77's question is simplified and belies other operations they're doing for which (they believe) the lazy operations `arrow` affords are a necessity. I suggest that unless you have an `arrow`-centric solution, this answer does not fit the unstated requirements.

Comment: Based on that (and the existing downvote), if there is nothing you can add, I suggest deleting it to recoup the reps and prevent further downvotes. Not a judgement, just a suggestion. Thanks!